# How to sort a list of sub-lists by the contents of sub-lists, where sub-lists contain strings and booleans?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list containing thousands of sub-lists. Each of these sub-lists contain a combination of mixed strings and boolean values, for example:

```
lst1 = [['k', 'b', False], ['k', 'a', True], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'a' , False], ...]
```

I want to sort this list in accordance with the contents of the sub-lists, like:

```
lst2 = [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a' , False], ['a', 'b', 'a'], ['k', 'a', True], ['k', 'b', False], ...]
```

I've tried sorting it like this:

```
lst2 = sorted([list(sorted(x)) for x in lst1])
print(lst2)
```

This doesn't work because of the combination of boolean values with strings in some fields, so I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'bool' and 'str'`.

I've also tried a brute force method, creating every possible combination and then checking them to see if which are in the first list:

```
col1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, ..., True, False]
col2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, ..., True, False]
col3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, ..., True, False]
lst2 = list()
for t1 in col1:
    for t2 in col2:
        for t3 in col3:
            test_sublist = [t1, t2, t3]
            if test_sublist in lst1:
            lst2.append(test_sublist)
```

This way works well enough, because I'm able to automatically create sorted lists for each column, `col 1`, `col 2`, and `col 3`, but it takes way too long to run (more than 3 days).

Is there a better solution for sorting mixed string/boolean lists like these?

Comment: Are `a-z`, `True` and `False` the only possible elements?

Comment: Not quite. `a-z` can actually be a string of any size, I just simplified the problem for ease of explanation. `'adverb'`, `'verb'`, `'adjective'`, `'noun'`, etc. are the types of things that are written. I actually think that the only boolean used is `False`, but I want to allow for the possibility that `True` could be used at some stage.

Comment: @AdeDoyle It might be useful to add this last comment of yours to the main body of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These handle any lengths, not just length 3. And bools in any places, not just the last column. For keying, they turn each element of each sublist into a tuple.

---

Solution 1:

```
sorted(lst1, key=lambda s: [(e is False, e is True, e) for e in s])
```

Turns strings into `(False, False, thestring)` so they come first.
Turns `True` into `(False, True, True)` so it comes next.
Turns `False` into `(True, False, False)` so it comes last.

Though I think of it the reverse way, as in "First deprioritize `False`, then deprioritize `True`". The general form is `key=lambda x: (shall_come_last(x), x)`.

---

Solution 2:

```
sorted(lst1, key=lambda s: [((e is True) + 2 * (e is False), e) for e in s])
```

Turns strings into `(0, thestring)` so they come first.
Turns `True` into `(1, True)` so it comes next.
Turns `False` into `(2, False)` so it comes last.

---

Solution 3:

```
sorted(lst1, key=lambda s: [(0, e) if isinstance(e, str) else (2 - e,) for e in s])
```

Turns strings into `(0, thestring)` so they come first.
Turns `True` into `(1,)` so it comes next.
Turns `False` into `(2,)` so it comes last.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a key handler for `sorted` that pads an element if it contains a boolean:

```
lst1 = [['k', 'b', False], ['k', 'a', True], ['a', 'a' , False], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'a']]
result = sorted(lst1, key=lambda x:(x, False) if isinstance(x[-1], str) else (x[:-1]+[x[-2]], not x[-1]))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', False], ['a', 'b', 'a'], ['k', 'a', True], ['k', 'b', False]]
```

Comment: Instead of using `sorted(map(...))` and then doing a list comprehension to "undo" the `map`, you could just do `sorted(lst1, key=Val)`.

Comment: @kaya3 That is much better than the comprehension, thank you

Comment: It doesn't look right. For example, you leave `[['a', 'b', False], ['a', 'b', True]]` as is, even though OP's code shows `True` coming before `False`.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I think that depends on how the OP wants to prioritize an actual occurrence of a comparison between `True` and `False`. The section from the OP's code that you are referring to has `True` before `False` because the second elements are being compared: `'a'` and `'b'`. Thus, the list with `l[1] => 'a'` comes before `l1[1] => 'b'`. I think the string comparison takes priority over the boolean.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you talking about their example data? I'm talking about their *solution*. In particular their `col1`, `col2` and `col3`.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yes, I am referring to their example data, compared to their desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that Booleans precede the strings in the sorted list, `pandas` would offer a simple interface for this task:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst1)
# Sort by all columns, from left to right.
df.sort_values(by=list(df.columns), inplace=True)
lst2 = df.values.tolist()
```

This results in the following output.

```
[['a', 'a', False],
 ['a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'b', 'a'],
 ['k', 'a', True],
 ['k', 'b', False]]
```

The approach generalizes well to None-values and numbers without modification.

---

If you really need the Booleans to appear at the end, you could rename the values temporarily. (I skip the `inplace=True` for better readability)

```
df = df.replace(False, "zFalse")
df = df.replace(True, "zTrue")
df = df.sort_values(by=list(df.columns))
df = df.replace("zFalse", False)
df = df.replace("zTrue", True)
lst2 = df.values.tolist()
```

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', False],
 ['a', 'b', 'a'],
 ['k', 'a', True],
 ['k', 'b', False]]
```

I agree that this is less appealing, but would work. Unfortunately, [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) doesn't support a sort-key argument to control the sort precedence.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(lst):
    pad = len(max(lst, key=lambda l: len(l)))
    def ssort(lst):
        newlst = list(map(lambda item: item if isinstance(item, str) else 'Ӿ' if item == True else "ӿ", lst))
        count = 0
        for l in newlst:
            if l == "ӿ" or l == "Ӿ":
                count += 1
        count = count + pad - len(newlst)
        while(count > 0):
            newlst.insert(0, 'ӿ')
            count -= 1
        return newlst
    lst.sort(key=lambda lst: ssort(lst))

st1 = [['k', 'b', False], ['k', 'a', True], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'a' , False], ['a', 'a', True]]
sort(st1)
print(st1)
```

**Output**

[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'a', True], ['a', 'a', False], ['k', 'a', True], ['k', 'b', False]]